# Layout measured size returning 0

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to fill a relative layout with 4 images of equal size. To do this I am trying to get the size of the layout then adjust the size of the images by dividing the layout size by 4. However, I am not getting the size of the layout properly; it keeps returning 0 (both the height and the width). Here is what I have so far:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    layoutHeight = mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
    layoutWidth = mainLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
    Log.d("Layout dimensions", layoutHeight + " " + layoutWidth);

}
```

As I understand it, onResume() will run after onCreate()? I originally had this section of code in onCreate() and it wasn't working there, but it also isn't working in onResume().

I also tried changing the lines

```
layoutHeight = mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
layoutWidth = mainLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
```

to

```
layoutHeight = mainLayout.getHeight();
layoutWidth = mainLayout.getWidth();
```

but that didn't work either.

Here is my XML, in case anyone wants to see that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bronzeView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bronze" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/silverView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/silver" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/goldView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/gold" />

    <!--<ImageView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/roseGoldView"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="76dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="137dp"-->
    <!--app:srcCompat="@drawable/rosegold_small"-->
    <!--tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="336dp"-->
    <!--tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="557dp" />-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/platinumView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/platinum" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You must use `ViewTreeObserver` or retrieve dimensions in `run()` method using `layout.post()...`

Comment: Can you show your xml please?

Comment: dimensions of any view can be measured only and only when view is fully rendered on screen, but in onResume() view is just created not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

`mainLayout.post(new Runnable(){
    layoutHeight = mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
    layoutWidth = mainLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
}`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to fill a relative layout with 4 images of equal size. To do this I am trying to get the size of the layout then adjust the size of the images by dividing the layout size by 4.

Have you considered using `ConstraintLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`? Then you could do all of this in XML without having to execute any code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image4"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```